# DDM to DD Geographic Coordinate Conversion Algorithm

Tags: c#, math, coordinates, converters, coordinate

I have used http://www.pgc.umn.edu/tools/conversion to convert

52 37.9418 N
01.18.8020 E
(DDM I Think?)

To

Latitude 52.632363
Longitude 1.313367

This seems to be very accurate, i have played about with the calculations to convert these values myself but they never seem to be accurate.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion

What is the math behind this convertion?

Comment: Probably you use the wrong coordinate system (or the formulas for the wrong one). The first link you point to uses WGS84 which is the most widely used global coordinate system. Apart from WGS84 there exist a huge number of others, some not global but local. So if you pick the formula, and you want to make sure they yield the same results, you need to use the correct system. But then, programming the formula is not really hard.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @user2225104: The formula for converting DDM to DD is not in any way shape or form dependent on WGS84, NAD27, or anything else of that nature.  It's a simple conversion from decimal minutes to decimal hours.

Comment: @Dan-o He wrote "DDM I think". So I thought that the lat long he has might stem from some other coordinate system. In nearly all of them you have Lat/Long values but this does not mean that they all have the same elliptical parameters and maybe local corrections. Thus, I mused that this could be a reason for his problems, given that I did not think that it is this basic conversion which gives him trouble o.O.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//Parsing the DDM format is left as an excersize to the reader,
//  as is converting this code snippet into a usable function.
double inputDegrees = 52;
double inputMinutes = 37.9418;
double latitude = inputDegrees + (inputMinutes/60);  // 52.632363
```